# Python: close a pyglet window

Tags: python-3.x, window, pyglet, openai-gym

I am using a pixel based [gym](https://gym.openai.com/) environment in my code. For some reasons, I need to modify the `render` function. Using `pyglet`, I have created my own class `ShowRender` with a `render` and a `close` function:

```py
import cv2
import pyglet
from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering

class ShowRender(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.viewer = rendering.SimpleImageViewer()
        self.viewer.width = 512
        self.viewer.height = 512
        self.viewer.window = pyglet.window.Window(width=self.viewer.width, height=self.viewer.height,
                                                  display=self.viewer.display, vsync=False, resizable=True)

    def render(self, observation):
        self.viewer.imshow(observation)

    def close(self):
        self.viewer.close()
```

Function `render` works perfectly: a new window is created and displays the environment's pixels.
But when I use `close` function, the window stays open and does not disappear. Any advice to close it properly ? Thanks

Comment: Not sure how `gym` works or what `object` refers to. So I'm not sure how this magic class is inherited/instanciated via pyglet. But usually it's a `on_close(self, *args)` event being called, not actually `close()`. So try implement `on_close` instead?

Comment: I'm actually just looking for a way to close the `self.viewer.window`, i.e. the `pyglet.window`

Comment: got it, I just had to add `self.viewer.window.close()` ... -_-'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this so the question becomes marked as solved, after discussions in the comments above, the solution is pretty simple. calling `.close()` on the window object helped by doing `self.viewer.window.close()`:

```
import cv2
import pyglet
from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering

class ShowRender(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.viewer = rendering.SimpleImageViewer()
        self.viewer.width = 512
        self.viewer.height = 512
        self.viewer.window = pyglet.window.Window(width=self.viewer.width, height=self.viewer.height,
                                                  display=self.viewer.display, vsync=False, resizable=True)

    def render(self, observation):
        self.viewer.imshow(observation)

    def close(self):
        self.viewer.window.close()
```